# Executing and sql String

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm currently working on an update statement for java. After you click the `button` it will get the integer data you put into the `textfield` and it will read the name from the dropdown and give the corresponding employee ID.  Database connection is done via a different class.

```
    ActionListener myActionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
            if (connection.openConnection()) {
                String ID = input1.getText();
                int orderID = Integer.parseInt(ID);

                String firstName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(firstName);
                System.out.println(orderID);
                if (firstName == "Patrick") {
                    int employeeId = 10;
                    String sql = "UPDATE barorder SET statusId=2, employeeId='" + employeeId + "' where id='" + orderID + "' ;";
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

This is what I got so far but I don't know how to execute the SQL String now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your current query is unsafe because it is open to SQL injection. I suggest you follow the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), and learn how to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PreparedStatement` to update query like this:

```
  ActionListener myActionListener = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            if (connection.openConnection())
            {
                String ID = input1.getText();
                int orderID = Integer.parseInt(ID);

                String firstName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(firstName);
                System.out.println(orderID);
                if (firstName == "Patrick")
                {
                    int employeeId = 10;

                    String sql = "UPDATE barorder SET statusId=2, employeeId= ? where id= ?";
                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(1, employeeId);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(2, orderID);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);

                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your answer is unsafe as it includes SQL injection. Consider posting an answer that includes a safe equivalent using a prepared statement.

Comment: Have updated my answer. Thank you so much for your valuable comment.

Comment: Your update is wrong as it doesn't use parameters to solve the sql injection problem, and on top of that using `execute update(String)` on a prepared statement must always fail according to the JDBC specification (in MySQL it will probably work for this specific example.

Comment: use ? to define the variables and add them with preparedstatement.setString(1,value)

Answer (score 0):

By using `PreparedStatement` you may solve your problem.

In my own project i have used this

```
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Signup(Username, password, Email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        prep.setString(1, UserName);
        prep.setString(2, Password);
        prep.setString(3, Email);

        prep.executeUpdate();
```

And you can get help form the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Both statements are imortant for this.

Comment: As: `PreparedStatement prep ..` and it's call  `prep.setString...`